# How to handle RESTful delete in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

How do I correctly use RESTful delete in Spring MVC controller? I have DAO that returns boolean when trying to delete some item.

I am trying to delete item. If everything was OK, just show list of items (deleted item won't be there anymore). If item cannot be removed, redirect to details page and say why it couldn't be deleted.

Do I need some special response status or something like this? Is my approach RESTful?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "items/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int itemId, Model model) {
    Item item = itemDao.get(id);

    // true -> can delete
    // false -> cannot delete, f.e. is FK reference somewhere
    boolean wasOk = itemDao.delete(item); 

    if (wasOk) {
        return "redirect:/items";
    }

    // will write to user which item couldn't be deleted
    model.addAttribute("item", item);
    return "items/error";
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you the issues with a delete can be fixed by the user, then this seems ok.  If there is nothing the user can do then perhaps an error code status would be more correct. The only failure I can imagine for a deletion would be an authorization failure, which would be a 401.  This could be set by adding a parameter to your method 'HttpServletResponse response'. Your code would become something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "items/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int itemId, Model model, HttpServletReponse response) {
    Item item = itemDao.get(id);

    // true -> can delete
    // false -> cannot delete, f.e. is FK reference somewhere
    boolean wasOk = itemDao.delete(item); 

    if (!wasOk) {
        // will write to user which item couldn't be deleted
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        model.addAttribute("item", item);
        return "items/error";   
    }

    return "redirect:/items";
}
```

You can substitue other status codes as appropriate, but that is the General idea.

You could also do something like:

```
    if (!wasOk) {
        throw new DataAccessException("Unable to delete item: " + item);
    }
```

And then have an annotated error handler in the same class

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleDataAccessException(DataAccessException ex) {
    // Do some stuff
    return "errorView";
}
```

Comment: OK but when I do it like that, how do I put stuff in model to be available on page resolved as "errorView" ? Before I throw exception I put "model.addAttribute("badItem", item)" ... but it ain't available at errorView.jsp page

Comment: You could return a `new ModelAndView("errorView", "badItem", ex.getItem())` from the controller, assuming you had a custom exception that could keep a reference to the item. Although that does seem a bit messy.

Answer (score 19):

You should consider to use [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) to indicate whether or not the delete operation succeeds rather than redirects. For example `HTTP 200 OK` (or `HTTP 204 No Content`) to indicate that the operation was successful, and `HTTP 404 Not Found` if the resource you are trying to access does not exist, `HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed` if the delete operation is not allowed, etc. Based on the response status, the client can decide whether or not to keep the referenced resource (in your case the object that is referenced by `item/{id}` ).

Since you are using Spring, you can annotate your controller methods with an appropriate [@ResponseStatus](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html), e.g. 
`@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)`

Additionally, Spring `HandlerExceptionResolver`already provides some status codes by [default](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers).

Comment: Okay let's say I want to use HTTP405 since resource cannot be deleted. How do I tell user which entity couldn't be deleted? Can I simply put it in the Model and than on JSP page try if there is such property in model?

Comment: It is the other way around. The *client* sends the id of the resource ,`items/{id}`, that it intends to delete, see my update.