# Redirect after DELETE

Tags: spring-mvc

First method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/version/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAllProducts() throws IOException {
    List<Product> products = productService.findAllProducts();

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("main");
    model.addObject("products", products);

    return model;
}
```

Second method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/version/products/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {

    Product productToDelete = productService.findById(id);
    if (productToDelete != null) {
        productService.deleteProduct(id);
    }

    return "redirect:/api/version/products";
}
```

After DELETE request I got this message:

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'DELETE' not supported

Third method working correctly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/version/products", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProduct(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String price) throws IOException {

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName(name);
    product.setPrice(new BigDecimal(price));
    productService.saveProduct(product);

    return "redirect:/api/version/products";
}
```

Comment: What is the request being made?  What method is it hitting?

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/a03b4f468e3844f9820bde7640d47d61.png

Comment: Does your getAllProducts work?

Comment: Yes, getAllProducts work correctly. It seems like redirect makes not GET but DELETE request.

Comment: Server side redirects in delete handlers are not recommended.Please follow the status code approach as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10340755/1679484. Can @Vitolds explain why his solution works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Try adding a GET request handler(redirect to some other page or something) with the same URL path as your DELETE handler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/version/products/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getProduct(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {


        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

I once had a problem like this and this solved it

2) try: "api/version/products/{id}" instead of "/api/version/products/{id}"

Comment: I tryed this , didn't help =(

Comment: Third method redirect to "/api/version/products/{id}" and work correctly

Comment: This solution may work but doesn't follow the rules for the HTTP verbs:  if the purpose is to delete then the correct HTTP method is DELETE rather than GET

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX to call a void delete method and then on success redirect to the page you want.

You will need JQuery dependency and simple js file reference to call this of course...

Something like this:

```
$('.deleteProductButton').on('click', function () {
                 var productId = $(this).attr('data-product-id');                
                 $.ajax({
                        type : "DELETE",
                        url : "/api/version/products/"+ productId,
                        success: function (result) {   
                            console.log(result);  
                            window.location = '/api/version/products'; // redirect          
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                    });

            });  

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/version/products/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {

    Product productToDelete = productService.findById(id);
    if (productToDelete != null) {
        productService.deleteProduct(id);
    }

}
```